# IBM Websphere deployment using wsadmin to rollout updates in High availability environment

Tags: websphere, wsadmin, rollout

We are currently deploying applications to cluster via WAS admin console. After updating the Application we Rollout updates instead of Saving the configurations. This rolls out the application server by server so that the application is continuously available. Now we need to automate this deployment using wsadmin command line tool. I am not sure how to do it.

A simple AppAdmin.update command with AdminConfig.save updates applications on the servers simultaneously producing downtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs here - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=scripting-updating-installed-applications-using-wsadmin-tool there is no "automatic" rollout via wsadmin scripting.

So probably you could write your script to do following:

- Disable automatic synchronization of the nodes
- Update application (the new app will only be on Dmgr for now)
- Sequentially sync nodes - that will deploy app to the servers on the given node
- Enable automatic synchronizaton

Comment: I have one question. do we need to restart nodes after any steps above?

Comment: @AhmedOmair, no the node synchronization doesnt require restart.

Comment: One more Question. If I use syncActiveNodes() will it do node synchronization in sequence or do we need to do synNode() one by one and wait for isAppReady() to return true before moving to Next node synchronization?

Comment: @AhmedOmair, its not obvious from the docs, and I dont have env at hand, so you would need to test it manually in your env ;-)